# Configure script to run at a regular interval on AWS EC2?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am a little new to AWS development so bear with me here. I have some scripts written in Typescript code that I am able to compile and run with node locally. What I would like to accomplish is moving these scripts to an EC2 instance (where the application that the scripts interact with exists), and have them run regularly (e.g. once every 24 hours) on the EC2 instance.

I'm obviously not looking for a comprehensive solution to my problem, but does anyone know if this is achievable? Does EC2 provide configuration for this? Would it be smart to use Lambda for any of the scripts? As I said I am new to AWS development and not quite sure the best way to implement a solution.

Comment: You can use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for this, which is a feature on any *nix system.

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux?